# PHP Give color in SELECT IFNULL(SUM(),0)

Tags: php, html, css, colors

I have an simple question how can I give color for 0 display in my code below :

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(qty), 0)
FROM   t_qty
WHERE  ...
```

In that code, if no data then it will show 0. Now I want to give the red color for that 0. So how can I do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: Show your PHP code that creates the HTML.

Comment: Ever considered PHP to count the rows, if the rows are 0 then `echo "<font color='red'>0</font>";` ?

Comment: I agree with @DarylGill just use something like `num_rows()` if its `0` then echo `'0'`

Comment: Wait.. It's maths your doing from SQL, just pull the results then `if ($Results !== 0){ /* font manipulating */ }`  something along those lines

Comment: font? some one suggested font  ?!?!